# CSS - divs positioning / shadow affects other

Tags: html, css

I have problem when i want to achieve this in css:

- Image in background - that's ok(ok it isnt visible in jsfiddle)
- One div in background to create something like shadow - that's ok
- To be everything else sharp enaugh. So tose element's must not be affected with any shadow properties. - THERE IS PROBLEM

"Shadow div" have attribute display fixed, and it is not parent of any other elements on site!
I don't know, why this opacity property affet on other element in same position?

Short HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="background"></div> 
    <div id="bodyBackground"></div>
    <div id="body">elements here looks darker</div>
</body>
```

[JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xkvrF/2/)
[Shorter JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkvrF/5/)

Comment: Your fiddle is too complex to match your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you set the opacity on the `content`.

```
#content {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 160px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    opacity:0.4;  <--- right here 
    filter:alpha(opacity=40); <--- and here 
}
```

Comment: let me da**! Thank u a lot!! realy.